# Centos7 'httpd' service not starting

Tags: centos, apache-2.4

I am not able to start my apache service in centos7.
Here is my journalctl -e result.

```
enter code here
    [root@qlntrk pam.d]# journalctl -xe
    Feb 06 07:28:05 qlntrk.com sshd[2391]: Failed password for root from 58.242.83.11 port 47194 ssh2
    Feb 06 07:28:06 qlntrk.com sshd[2391]: Failed password for root from 58.242.83.11 port 47194 ssh2
    Feb 06 07:28:07 qlntrk.com sshd[2391]: Failed password for root from 58.242.83.11 port 47194 ssh2
    Feb 06 07:28:07 qlntrk.com sshd[2391]: Failed password for root from 58.242.83.11 port 47194 ssh2
    Feb 06 07:28:08 qlntrk.com sshd[2391]: Failed password for root from 58.242.83.11 port 47194 ssh2
    Feb 06 07:28:09 qlntrk.com sshd[2391]: Failed password for root from 58.242.83.11 port 47194 ssh2
    Feb 06 07:28:09 qlntrk.com sshd[2391]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for root from 58.242.83.11 port 47194 ssh2 [preauth]
-- Unit httpd.service has begun starting up.
Feb 06 07:28:24 qlntrk.com sshd[2395]: pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "root"
Feb 06 07:28:25 qlntrk.com systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 06 07:28:25 qlntrk.com kill[2406]: kill: cannot find process ""
Feb 06 07:28:25 qlntrk.com systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 06 07:28:25 qlntrk.com systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit httpd.service has failed.
```

Apache Access Log :

```
54.39.100.61 - - [03/Feb/2019:03:12:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586"
109.173.40.29 - - [03/Feb/2019:03:12:14 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "https://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Bsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=2052.mhf8iA27ddRBnN3GnTJNwaviWpAholnz9GtCGTnPy7Y.592bb885899fd7e8363e6a21ace078195106d9ae&uuid=&state=_BLhILn4SxNIvvL0W45KSic66uCIg23qh8iRG98qeIXmeppkgUc0YD4hgzqAYr5iuWBiLZQy-rY&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1LdmtxcHpqQmU2dU5tYVlwd2xPZThPcklINUFidXh2ZWx0N3ZzUVlLSXNHcU9wYWhsV0tiRVFXUjJnYXNBUmhORDhFYU02YzNqT2ZJUXV3&b64e=2&sign=6cad9be581189005b123fac70153802b&keyno=0&cst=AiuY0DBWFJ7IXge4WdYJQaYgAYq7Jarr9EZ3-2YfDUgWOTEO_6wwpH_QbobMiT-yBt-68yoLcIDBh8xTQdkoZkQE1HXlIlQ218ih1JfRCw3avu7UGfUUVfRu045j-3qtC8voEApgZUm0GD0ShPyz1I_TDd6xsXAo&ref=orjY4mGPRjk5boDnW0uvlrrd71vZw9kp5uQozpMtKCXvzya1eNB8qvbLUvO794CgdbnZmMdloMdkfR6qB2deoeK1qxCCD8ZnBxige6Zlc7Y&l10n=ru&cts=1549159368762&mc=5.38327860459" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0; MASBJS)"
34.220.99.163 - - [03/Feb/2019:03:12:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"
82.80.230.228 - - [03/Feb/2019:03:12:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22"
54.39.100.61 - - [03/Feb/2019:03:12:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"
```

Apache Error Log :

```
[Sun Feb 03 03:12:02.579986 2019] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 20329] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Feb 03 03:12:02.582071 2019] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 20329] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun Feb 03 03:12:02.589849 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 20329] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Sun Feb 03 03:12:02.607009 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 20329] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/7.2.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Comment: What you see in access and error logs of apache?

Comment: command : sudo service httpd restart
"Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
"

Comment: On a side note: the entries *"Failed password for root from ... ssh"* indicates that you both allow root login for ssh and password authentication. You get much better security by preventing root logins (and require admins to log in with their personal account and use `sudo` ) and force ssh key based authentication.

Comment: @RonakChauhan, I ask for apache logs, not systemctl logs

Comment: @RomeoNinov Do you need error logs of apache error log ?

Comment: Yes, error and access logs of apache

Comment: Last Access Log 
"54.39.100.61 - - [03/Feb/2019:03:12:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586"
"

Comment: @RomeoNinov Last 3 error log
"[Sun Feb 03 03:12:02.579986 2019] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 20329] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Feb 03 03:12:02.582071 2019] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 20329] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun Feb 03 03:12:02.589849 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 20329] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
"

Comment: @RomeoNinov updated question.

Comment: It's most likely something wrong in a configuration file. Did you modify anything recently ?

Answer (score 0):

After Digging for 3 hours I found that issue with my SSL configuration file.
I renewed letsencrypt SSL certificate and then this issue came.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-centos-7

I used following steps to check this "httpd -t" but "Syntax OK".

Then from virtual host file I remove line for SSL certificate then it worked fine.
ex.

thank you for help.